# Producer Consumer using wait and notify : Consumer does not receive messages

Tags: java, wait, producer-consumer, notify

I have prepared a producer consumer using wait and notify mechanism in Java. Below is the code:

```
class Producer implements Runnable {

    private int i = 0;
    private ArrayList<Integer> arrayList;
    private static final int MAX_SIZE = 5; 

    public Producer(ArrayList<Integer> arrayList) {
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while(true) {
            try {
                produce(i++);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           
        }
    }

    private synchronized void produce(int i) throws InterruptedException {

        while(arrayList.size() == MAX_SIZE) {

            System.out.println("The Queue is Full. Producer thread needs to wait.");

            wait();         
        }
        arrayList.add(i);
        System.out.println("Added Element: "+i);
        notifyAll();
        Thread.sleep(3000);         
    }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable {

    private ArrayList<Integer> arrayList;

    public Consumer(ArrayList<Integer> arrayList) {
        this.arrayList = arrayList;
    }   

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while(true) {   
            try {
                consume();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
    }

    private synchronized void consume() throws InterruptedException {

        while(arrayList.isEmpty()) {

            System.out.println("The Queue is empty. Consumer thread needs to wait.");

            wait();                 
        }
        int data = arrayList.remove(0);
        System.out.println("Removed Element: "+data);
        notifyAll();
        Thread.sleep(3000);
    }   
}

public class ProducerConsumerExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        Thread producer = new Thread(new Producer(arrayList), "Producer Thread");
        Thread consumer = new Thread(new Consumer(arrayList), "Consumer Thread");       
        producer.start();
        consumer.start();       
    }
}
```

Below is the sample output

```
The Queue is empty. Consumer thread needs to wait.
Added Element: 0
Added Element: 1
Added Element: 2
Added Element: 3
Added Element: 4
The Queue is Full. Producer thread needs to wait.
```

The issue is that the consumer thread is either not getting the notification or the notification is getting lost. I have tried understanding the code but not getting any clue as to where I am going wrong.

Comment: Producer Consumer with Blocking example is already available, search in google.

Comment: this is not how `notifyAll()` works. threads are supposed to request exclusive (=synchronized) access to the `ArrayList` and then the `ArrayList` object is doing the  `notifyAll()`

Answer (score 2):

> The issue is that the consumer thread is either not getting the notification or the notification is getting lost

The reason why this happens is that the `Producer` and the `Consumer` are not  *Synchronizing* on the same instance. They are independently *Synchronizing* on their own instance (i.e `this`). To fix this, both the `Producer` and the `Consumer` can *Synchronize* on the instance of the `ArrayList` or another *shared* object.

Comment: Not only do they need to synchronize on the same instance, they need to wait and notify on that instance.

Comment: I am still confused. "Head First Java" book says "You don't put a lock on the bank account itself; you lock the method that does the banking transaction". "You don't lock the data itself, you synchronize the methods that access that data". Similarly here I am not locking the shared resource - ArrayList I am synchronizing the methods namely - "produce" and "consume". What's wrong with that? And I suppose they are synchronizing on the same instance as I am passing the same ArrayList to both the producer and consumer classes. Am i missing something here? Please clarify and clear my concepts.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel That is implied since `wait` and `notify` cannot be called outside a synchronized context.

Comment: @user10675448 I don't have a copy of the *Head First Java* book. I pointed out the issue in the code. The producer and consumer in the example lock on two different instances. I suggested that you lock on the `ArrayList` because this is the shared mutable state between two classes. If you wish to lock on something other than the `ArrayList`, make sure both classes share the instance of that class.(By creating your own lock object and syncrhonizing on it for example). Another alternative is  to put the producer and consumer code in a single class so that both lock on the same instance (`this`).

Comment: @CKing: How the producer and consumer in the example lock on two different instances when I am passing the same ArrayList instance to both the producer and consumer classes. Please clarify? I want to clean my concepts.

Comment: @user10675448 1) `private synchronized void produce` in `Producer` is an instance method. This method is synchronized. This means that threads will acquire a lock on the instance on which this method is called (which is a `Producer` instance). 2) Similarly, `private synchronized void consume()` in `Consumer` is an instance method. This method is synchronized. This means that threads will acquire a lock on the instance on which this method is called (which is a `Consumer` instance). From 1) and 2), we can see that there are two different instances on which a lock is acquired.

Comment: @CKing You're right, but I don't think that is always immediately clear to people new to Java synchronization.

Answer (score 0):

Producer and Consumer are synchronized on this of its own instance.But it should be synchronized on common object and same object we have to call wait and notify. I have modified your code to work accordingly.Please check

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

class Producer implements Runnable {


    private ArrayList<Integer> arrayList;
    private static final int MAX_SIZE = 5; 

    public Producer(ArrayList<Integer> arrayList) {
        this.arrayList = arrayList;

    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while(true) {
            try {
                produce();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }           
        }
    }

    private void produce() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (arrayList) {
            while (arrayList.size() == MAX_SIZE) {

                System.out.println("The Queue is Full. Producer thread needs to wait.");

                arrayList.wait();
            }
            System.out.println("Added Element: " + ProducerConsumerExample.i);
            arrayList.add(ProducerConsumerExample.i++);
            arrayList.notify();
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }
    }
}

class Consumer implements Runnable {

    private ArrayList<Integer> arrayList;

    public Consumer(ArrayList<Integer> arrayList) {
        this.arrayList = arrayList;

    }   

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while(true) {   
            try {
                consume();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } 
        }
    }

    private void consume() throws InterruptedException {
        synchronized (arrayList) {

            while (arrayList.isEmpty()) {

                System.out.println("The Queue is empty. Consumer thread needs to wait.");
                arrayList.wait();
            }

            int data = arrayList.remove(--ProducerConsumerExample.i);
            System.out.println("Removed Element: " + data);
            arrayList.notify();
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }
    }   
}

public class ProducerConsumerExample {
    static int i = 0;
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ArrayList<Integer> arrayList = new ArrayList<Integer>();

        Thread producer = new Thread(new Producer(arrayList), "Producer Thread");
        Thread consumer = new Thread(new Consumer(arrayList), "Consumer Thread");       
        producer.start();
        consumer.start();       
    }
}
```

Output : -

```
Added Element: 0
Added Element: 1
Added Element: 2
Added Element: 3
Added Element: 4
The Queue is Full. Producer thread needs to wait.
Removed Element: 4
Removed Element: 3
Removed Element: 2
Removed Element: 1
Removed Element: 0
The Queue is empty. Consumer thread needs to wait.
Added Element: 0
Added Element: 1
Added Element: 2
Added Element: 3
Added Element: 4
The Queue is Full. Producer thread needs to wait.
Removed Element: 4
Removed Element: 3
```

Note :- Need not to wait till Arraylist reached max size,try to consume it once it was produce by producer.